# Neo4j Out of Memory Error while deleting duplicate relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have over 12 million relationship records in my neo4j database. while importing the data by mistake some duplicate relationships were created which I want to delete now. Whenever I executed the following query

```
MATCH (a:person)-[r:IS_A_FRIEND]->(b:person)
WITH a, b, COLLECT(r) AS rr
WHERE SIZE(rr) > 1
WITH rr
LIMIT 1000
FOREACH (r IN TAIL(rr) | DELETE r)
```

Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError error occurs.
I have following neo4j conf

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=8G
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=16G
```

How can I get rid of this error and delete duplicate relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query *might* execute without running out of memory:

```
MATCH (a:person)-[:IS_A_FRIEND]->(b)
FOREACH(x IN TAIL([(a)-[r:IS_A_FRIEND]->(b) | r]) | DELETE x)
```

The [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) (in neo4j 4.0.3) of this particular query does not show an [Eager](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/operators/#query-plan-eager) operation, which may be what is causing your OOM condition.